# LibGDX Texture blending

Tags: libgdx

[image: Blending example]

I have two textures 1 and 2, and a "mask" image 3. I'd like to interpolate between the two textures by using the mask image, and get something like 4. I'm not really sure where to start, as I never did "blending" like this before. Can I do this with the `SpriteBatch` class, or do I have to make my own shader for this effect?